# Is a long shower the main cause of this leak? Would clear silicone on all grout lines help?

Tags: shower, grout, sealant, silicone

We are in a brand new house for the past 1 year.  From the first month onward, we have noticed water coming out from under the door jamb pictured here.

When we put a plastic sheet all over the shower, there was no leak.  This is how we determined that the grout was the cause.  The builder has been good about coming back to re-grout the tiles, and re-silicone the shower base.  The leak still occurred.

They came back to put a colorant/sealant on the grout.  Better, but still leaking.  Again, putting up the plastic sheet stopped all leaking.  Am I taking too long a shower? (*20 minutes once/week, all other days 10min*).   Does grout have a limit?

These are good builders and stand by their work.  Definitely not a plumbing problem.  [image: picture of the door jamb after 1 year of slow leaking]

Comment: A shower should not leak no matter how long it is  on.

Comment: Are you sure it's not running out of the corner of the shower, wall and glass door? Isolate the areas with some duct tape,  the plastic sheet is too broad

Comment: Those are big tiles, so the grout area seems small enough that you shouldn't get much leakage through them.  In addition, I would expect any grout leakage to go inside of the wall and under the floor tiles, not end up on top of the floor tiles.  Try putting PVC tape (electrical tape) over the grout and see if the leak still occurs.  My guess is that it will still occur because the cause is somewhere else.

Comment: It's hard to say with this picture, but it doesn't look like there is _any_ sealant between the glass and the wall. That would be my #1 suspect. It's also hard to tell, but the sealant at the bottom of the door looks like it's got a gap near the junction with the wall - that would be my #2 suspect. If this is the end of the shower nearest the shower head, it could be that after 15+ minutes, there's enough splashing off of you to work its way out here, while shorter showers aren't getting enough splashing to drip out at this point.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a typical problem related to installing tile directly onto either regular drywall or the type called green board.

A far better installation is to install tile onto cement board and even better is to coat the cement board with a paint on sealer such as RedGuard before hanging the tiles.

One last thing is that the cement board really needs to be installed after the shower base is pushed up against the walls so that the cement board can come down past the turned up lips on the wall sides of the base.

Based upon this you should have a discussion about how the tile was originally installed. It  may very well have been done at less than current best practices in the industry to save building costs, especially if this house was built in a large tract or building project in a mass produced way.